# SSH CA: How to sign a host key with custom port?

Tags: ssh, openssh, certificates

I have a server whose `sshd` listens on a non-standard port, say for example, 8022. I tried to sign its host key like this:

```
ssh-keygen -s ibug_ca -I example -h -n '[example.com]:8022' ssh_host_rsa_key.pub
```

And then I added this to `sshd_config` and ran `systemctl reload ssh.service`:

```
HostCertificate /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key-cert.pub
```

Now when I try to SSH onto the server using `ssh -p 8022 root@example.com`, OpenSSH client shows this:

```
Certificate invalid: name is not a listed principal
The authenticity of host '[example.com]:8022 ([example.com]:8022)' can't be established.
```

This isn't the case when I sign a certificate for a server with SSH port being 22 (standard). I'm sure I'm doing everything else correctly because I've done this many times.

What is the correct way to sign for a non-standard SSH port?

Comment: I've looked at [the code](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/cdf1d0a9f5d18535e0a18ff34860e81a6d83aa5c/sshkey.c#L2906) and tried to backtrack how it's called, but I wouldn't be surprised if you simply can't restrict the signature to a certain port. (That should be easy to verify for you – does the host cert not work when you run on a non-standard port?)

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz Oh yes, it was stupid of me to disregard that. It actually works for an arbitrary port, so the answer is just to omit the port when specifying principals. You'll get the green tick if you post your discovery as an answer.